# Android PreferenceScreen password protection

Tags: android

In my application I would like to have parts of my preferences password protected. There's not really the need to have them "really" secured - it's just that some settings should be only changed "if you know what you do" (it's an enterprise app).

So my preference hierarchy looks something like this:

```
PreferenceScreen
+-- PreferenceScreen
    +-- SettingA
    +-- SettingB
+-- PreferenceScreen (this one should be password protected)
    +-- SettingC
    +-- SettingD
```

The problem is, I can't find any way to intercept the clicking of the preferencescreen - I tried to override the `onPreferenceTreeClicked` method, but that didn't work:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) {
    if(userHasEnteredCorrectPassword) {
        return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Obviously because `super.onPreferenceTreeClick(...)` just start's an fragment in case the preference has set it.

I also tried to set the `onClickListener` of the preference in the `onCreate` of the PreferenceFragment - like this:

```
findPreference("secure_preference_screen").setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        if(userHasEnteredCorrectPassword) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

But that won't intercept the click as well.

Is there anyone out there who could possibly know how to implement such a feature?

Comment: Can you share the answer with the code?

Comment: I'd really love to. Unfortunately I haven't worked on Android for years and I don't have access to the codebase anymore. It was something along "Popup a dialog with a textfield, asking the user for a password" catch the callback in the fragment - if password does not match just close the activity (`finish()`) and toast a message "Password incorrect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just close the fragment if the user don't have the password. Catch it in where you can. It doesn't really matters

Comment: Didn't think of that idea :) Thanks. Just one more question: Do you have any idea how to "get back" to the previous screen? `getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()` won't work (nothing happens) and `getActivity().onBackPressed()` just closes the activity.

Comment: Open new question for that, there are many ways to do it. One solution is just calling finishing the current fragment, and it suppose to go back

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this by calling

```
override fun onNavigateToScreen(preferenceScreen: PreferenceScreen) {
    if (preferenceScreen.key == "protected_screen_key") {
        // do noting
    } else {
        super.onNavigateToScreen(preferenceScreen)
    }
}
```